# How can I use a for loop to omit entries from a vector?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

Here is my initial thought,

```
vector <- c(x,y,z)  

for(x in vector){  
print(vector[-x])  
}
```

I want to return y,z first, then x,z and then x,y. How would I go about this? The other answers on here seem to be about permanently removing an element from a vector which I don't want to do.

Thanks

Comment: `for(x in seq_along(vector)){print(vector[-x])}`

Comment: You probably find heaps of alternatives if you search for "leave-one-out"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lapply` to loop on indices

```
vector <- c(1,2,3)
lapply(seq_along(vector),function(i) vector[-i])

# [[1]]
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 2
```